# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request on invoke-restmethod using powershell on using OAUTH2 to upload file in google drive

Tags: powershell, google-drive-api, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to upload JSON file in google drive using Powershell. I have generated an OAUTH credentials to connect to google drive and using this credentials to upload JSON file in the google drive but I am receiving an 400 Bad Request error at Invoke-restmethod. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have gone through lots of site but no luck.Any helps will be appreciated.

My code:-

```
$ClientID="xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
$ClientSecret="xxxxxx"
$RefreshToken="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"

$params = @{
Uri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
Body = @(
 "refresh_token=$RefreshToken", 
 "client_id=$ClientID",         
 "client_secret=$ClientSecret", 
 "grant_type=refresh_token"
    
 ) -join '&'
 Method = 'Post'
 ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 }
 $accessToken = (Invoke-RestMethod @params).access_token

# Change this to the file you want to upload
$SourceFile = 'C:\check.json'

# Get the source file contents and details, encode in base64
$sourceItem = Get-Item $sourceFile
$sourceBase64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($sourceItem.FullName))
$sourceMime = [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($sourceItem.FullName)

# If uploading to a Team Drive, set this to 'true'
$supportsTeamDrives = 'false'

# Set the file metadata
$uploadMetadata = @{
originalFilename = $sourceItem.Name
name = $sourceItem.Name
description = $sourceItem.VersionInfo.FileDescription
#parents = @('my-drive') 
#teamDriveId = ‘teamDriveId’            
}

# Set the upload body
$uploadBody = @"
--boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
$($uploadMetadata | ConvertTo-Json)
--boundary
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: $sourceMime
$sourceBase64
--boundary--
"@

# Set the upload headers
$uploadHeaders = @{
"Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
"Content-Type" = '"application/json"; boundary=boundary'
"Content-Length" = $uploadBody.Length
}

# Perform the upload
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?    uploadType=multipart&supportsTeamDrives=$supportsTeamDrives" -Method Post -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body $uploadBody
```

[Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuSnX.png)

Comment: Every server is different.  A request contains a URI, HTTP Header(s), and a Body.  Error 400 indicates the connection completed and probably the credentials are good.  The server did not like the combination of the Headers and Body.  It looks like it is probably the MIME.  Mime attachments start with two dashes on a new line.  The Content-Type should be multipart.  See following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)